# Expression-Based Access Control do not working as explain in spring security document for 6.0.2 also tried 6.0.5 the issue persist

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I am try to implement spring authorization by following the document provided by spring https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/expression-based.html. My code is given below:

1. application.yaml

```
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resource-server:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: ${realms.url}
```

2. And the java code is below:

```java
package security.rand.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionAuthorizationManager;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                        authorize.requestMatchers("/test/**")
                                .access(new WebExpressionAuthorizationManager("@webSecurity.check(authentication,request)"))

                )
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().csrf().disable()
                .oauth2ResourceServer( OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt
                )
                .build();
    }
}
```

```java
package security.rand.config;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class WebSecurity {
    public boolean check(Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request) {
                return true;
    }
}
```

```java
package security.rand.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class RestControllerExample {
    @GetMapping("/test/{id}")
    public String getId( @PathVariable("id") String id){
        return "your id is : " + id;
    }
}
```

```bash
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/test/112' --header "Authorization: Bearer $(token)"
```

Unfortunately I'm getting 403 error instead of 200 with following error:

```
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1057E: No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'webSecurity'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.BeanReference.getValueInternal(BeanReference.java:51) ~[spring-expression-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:55) ~[spring-expression-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:91) ~[spring-expression-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:117) ~[spring-expression-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:309) ~[spring-expression-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:30) ~[spring-security-core-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
DefaultHttpSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultHttpSecurityExpressionHandler();
expressionHandler.setApplicationContext(context);
WebExpressionAuthorizationManager authorization = new WebExpressionAuthorizationManager("@webSecurity.checkUserId(authentication,#userId)");
authorization.setExpressionHandler(expressionHandler);
http
    .authorizeHttpRequests(exchange -> exchange
        .requestMatchers("/user/{userId}/**").access(authorization)
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    )
    .formLogin(withDefaults());
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12974

Answer (score 0):

To get this working, here is how I proceed:

1. force the component name to match exactly what is in the `WebExpressionAuthorizationManager` constructor

```java
@Component("webSecurity")
public static class WebSecurity {
    public boolean check(Authentication auth, HttpServletRequest request) {
        return auth instanceof JwtAuthenticationToken jwt && jwt.isAuthenticated();
    }
}
```

2. force the application context in the `HttpSecurityExpressionHandler` in the `WebExpressionAuthorizationManager`

```java
@Bean
WebExpressionAuthorizationManager webExpressionAuthorizationManager(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    var securityExpressionHandler = new DefaultHttpSecurityExpressionHandler();
    // Force the usage of the application context where the component is defined
    securityExpressionHandler.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

    // be sure to change "@webSecurity" if you use another name for the @Component above
    var authorizationManager = new WebExpressionAuthorizationManager(
        "@webSecurity.check(authentication,request)");
    authorizationManager.setExpressionHandler(securityExpressionHandler);
    return authorizationManager;
}
```

3. use this `WebExpressionAuthorizationManager`

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, WebExpressionAuthorizationManager webExpressionAuthorizationManager) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                        authorize.requestMatchers("/test/**")
                                .access(webExpressionAuthorizationManager)

                )
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().csrf().disable()
                .oauth2ResourceServer( OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt
                )
                .build();
    }
```

No wonder why I prefer, when possible, to configure `authorizeHttpRequests` with `permitAll()` to a few path matchers and `isAuthenticated()`as default. I then fine tune access control with a custom DSL in method security annotations. Sample [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_specialized_oauthentication) where I end with: `@PreAuthorize("is(#username) or isNice() or onBehalfOf(#username).can('greet')")` (where `username` is a path variable).

I know this is not the direction spring-security team is heading to, but I find this much more readable & easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is given [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12928) Which is following:

```
.access((authentication, context) ->
    new AuthorizationDecision(webSecurity.check(authentication.get(), context.getRequest())))
```

However the example do not have any expression-based solution.

Comment: Have you solely tried the answer above? Because it is expression based (and works)